# c++ custom operator new

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator

Hi I was recently doing some reading and decided to try implement a custom operator new, so I could log to a text file when memory is allocated and deleted to find memory leaks.

One of the problems I have immediately come across is that when I overloaded the new function and put a print in there, the function is called twice.

I was wondering if this is correct and if so why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    void* storage = malloc(size);
    std::cout << "Hello World! ";
    return storage;
}
int main()
{
    std::string *s = new std::string("test");
    std::cout << *s;
    return 0;
}
```

results:

> Hello World! Hello World! test

Edit: Tried without the string class and now it only does it once. I assume there is something underneath that creates it twice with lazy initialization. Would still like some clarification though.

Comment: There are tools available for this that will make your life a lot easier and are much more robust than simply providing custom `new` and `delete` operators. Spend your time learning how to use them instead.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious it is for my personal learning purposes

Comment: `new` is invoked twice because it is called one to create the `string` and then again to create the buffer that holds the string data.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I tried with an empty string "std::string *s = new std::string();" still done twice

Comment: A debugger, a breakpoint in your code, and a backtrace at each stoppage would be rather telling. Have you tried that? In comment to your edit, how do you think `std::string` allocates the buffer it will retain for the copy of the data you're passing it?

Comment: It's likely that the implementation `std::string` you are using adds a _null terminator_ to the end of the empty string. This requires at least one byte which in turn requires a buffer. Again, the implementation you are using apparently allocates one.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious After running through the debugger, that seems likely what is happening. However the size of the second creation is 8 instead of the suspected 1 for the size of a char.

Comment: It's an implementation detail, let it go or it will drive you to drink cheap whiskey. Accept it and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` is a class that allocates memory on the heap for storing its data. By design this requires two calls to `new`, one to allocate storage for the actual string class, and one to allocate the char array to store your text.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void* operator new(std::size_t size)
{
    void* storage = malloc(size);
    std::cout << "Asked for: " << size
        << ", at: " << storage << std::endl;
    return storage;
}

struct A
{
    char * data;
    A() {data = new char[10];}
    ~A() {delete[] data;}
};


int main()
{
    A* ptr = new A;
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
Asked for: 8, at: 0x1f68010
Asked for: 10, at: 0x1f68030
```